# I can't get my javascript to toggle my login dropdown. Why is javascript not connecting to my html?

Tags: javascript, html

I checked and rechecked my script link but it's not connecting to html. I must be doing something wrong but I don't see it.

I'm trying to connect javascript to the Log in button, so it shows and hides the log in form.
'''

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.lenth; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
 <div id="login">
          <ul class="login_signup">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
                Log in <span>▼</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown_content">
                <form>
                  <fieldset id="inputs">
                    <input id="username" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Your email address" required>
                    <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset id="actions">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Keep me signed in</label>
                  </fieldset>
                </form>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li id="signup">
              <a href="">Sign up</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

I would like to connect this js to the login button in html.

Comment: "I would like to connect this js to the login button in html." Unclear what that means

Comment: Check your js import path.. change  `src="/js/script.js"` to `src="./js/script.js"`

Comment: I tried changing path to src="./js/script.js" no change still not connecting. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is `getElementById()`  without the **s** in Element**s**, because there can be only one element with a given ID

Also, you if you want to use relative paths you should remove the **/** from `src="/js/script.js"`. / means start from the root path of your web server, and without it it means search the file starting from the file you are on right now.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.lenth; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
 <style>
 .dropdown_content {
    display: none;
 }
 .show {
    display: inherit !important;
 }
 </style>
 <div id="login">
          <ul class="login_signup">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
                Log in <span>▼</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown_content">
                <form>
                  <fieldset id="inputs">
                    <input id="username" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Your email address" required>
                    <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset id="actions">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Keep me signed in</label>
                  </fieldset>
                </form>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li id="signup">
              <a href="">Sign up</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you it was the s in elements.

Answer (score 0):

You may change your javascript path from `src="/js/script.js"` to `src="./js/script.js"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
src="js/script.js"
```

or

```
src="../js/script.js"
```

If you can share your folder structure I can update my answer